# Book series about a troupe of washed-up and out-of-work actors who buy a ship and travel the galaxy performing

Tags: story-identification, books

The story starts with a young man escaping to NYC to avoid a shotgun wedding. He rescues an elderly man being mugged in an alley. The man turns out to be a washed-up, once famous actor in an old popular children's program.  The country seems to be far trending towards authoritarianism.  That’s an undercurrent.

The old man is part of a group of washed-up/unemployed actors and theater people who have pooled their money and purchased a ship to tour the settled galaxy and perform plays.  They hire the young man be a stagehand/jack-of-all-trades. The government tries to stop them just before they take off but isn’t in time. They begin their tour leaving a trail of unintended revolution behind them.

There are two books that I know of. I’d like to find out the author’s name and if the series was ever finished.

Answer (score 20):

That's [Christopher Stasheff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Stasheff)'s '[Starship Troupers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troupers)' series.

The main character (the young man you mention, an engineering student with a background in martial arts, fleeing a potential shotgun-wedding) is Ramou Lazarian, although the perspective alternates between him (the neophyte) and Horace Burbage (the experienced actor who Ramou rescues from a mugging), with them somewhat acting as foils for each other.

The trend toward authoritarianism is a common one in his books, as is the fight against it, which this series quietly involves.  (It's better known in the 'Warlock' series, but shows up in most of his stories.)

There were actually four books, three of which were published traditionally:

- A Company Of Stars (1991)
- We Open On Venus (1993)
- A Slight Detour (1994)

Stasheff then self-published the last one: [THE UNKNOWN GUEST](http://christopher.stasheff.com/fiction/DDT/troupers_book4_chpt_01.htm) on his website, and it mostly wraps up the plot and the various loose ends.

[image: A company of Stars][image: We Open on Venus][image: A Slight Detour]

Comment: If you like the theater, you may enjoy the books -- almost every character is a significant reference to someone in theatrical history, and the books will give you an interesting intro to theater (something Stasheff taught) via Ramou learning it from the experienced members of the troupe.